# Bug on file upload

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

im developing an application in jsf with primefaces, and i found a bug in fileUpload. When i refresh the page this component 
appears distorted

I tried: 
1 - remove style an styleClass
2 - remove draganddrop support, remove mode atribute...
3 - put a form inside of dialog instead outside
3 - create component from current context application

The file upload is inside a p:outputPanel > h:form > p:dialog > p:panelgrid

```java
PanelGrid childPanelGrid = (PanelGrid) app.createComponent(PanelGrid.COMPONENT_TYPE);


                    FileUpload fileUpload = (FileUpload) app.createComponent(FileUpload.COMPONENT_TYPE);
                    fileUpload.setId("fileUpload_id");
                    fileUpload.setStyle("height: 230px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid  #e6e6e6; border-radius: 10px;");
                    fileUpload.setDragDropSupport(true);
                    fileUpload.setLabel("Selecionar documentos");
                    fileUpload.setCancelLabel("Cancelar");
                    fileUpload.setUploadLabel("Enviar");
                    fileUpload.setStyleClass("removeBordaFileUpload");
                    fileUpload.setInvalidSizeMessage("Tamanho máximo do arquivo excedido");
                    fileUpload.setSizeLimit(10000000L);
                    fileUpload.setAllowTypes("/(\\.|\\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|txt|rtf|doc|docx)$/");
                    fileUpload.setInvalidFileMessage("O formato do arquivo informado não é suportado");
                    fileUpload.setFileUploadListener(createMethodExpression("#{testeSalvarMenu.handleFileUpload}", void.class, FileUploadEvent.class));
                    fileUpload.setUpdate("formTeste:tabview_id:formDocumentos:dataTableDocumentos formTeste:tabview_id:formEnviarDocumentos:dialog_documento_id"); /**Alteracao em relacao ao estatico*/
                    childPanelGrid.getChildren().add(fileUpload);

                    dialogChildPanelGrid.getChildren().add(childPanelGrid);
```

When refresh the page i expected this
 https://drive.google.com/open?id=1i_IiAVAKekE1GDza5tvpf3KJBMDHclSN

but when refresh page i got this 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Vm42u84kONh9Gt2B6PjPXq13JfFzX_4O

Comment: start with reading [mcve]  and [ask] and https://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info, but most of all, debug with the browser developer tools (basic webdevelopment thing)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: put a fileupload tag in the xhtml with css atribute visibility: "hidden", only making this can work fine.

Comment: Great you 'solved' it, but this is a very weird solution for an unclear problem. Unless you create a clear [mcve] with the question, the answer is sort of useless.